# Why SpringBootTest with DEFINED_PORT can not be used along with TestRestTemplate for integration test?

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing

I try to write an integration test using `TestRestTemplate`, but it can not be injected when using `DEFINED_PORT` inside `@SpringBootTest` (only using `RANDOM_PORT`), is it possible to use it with TestRestTemplate ?

```
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class SampleApiControllerIntegrationTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private Integer port;

    private final static Integer TEST_DEFINED_PORT = 8060;


    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Please add some code instead of describing it.

Comment: try add src/test/resources/application.properties and add ```server.port=PORTYOUWANT``` it should start with that.